# pickerview and its selected value should be trimmed if comes 0

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I have a pickerview in some view with 6 component and all component have same array which is 0 to  9 integer no.s now i have to select one row from every component. and selected values print on a textfield. it is happening but now the question if user select  000130 (i.e example) then on the textfield it should be written 130. how can do it.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{



    str_final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@",
                           [orderValueArr objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]],
                           [orderValueArr objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]],
                           [orderValueArr objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]],
                           [orderValueArr objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:3]],
                           [orderValueArr objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:4]],
                           [orderValueArr objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:5]]];
 NSString *trimMe = str_final;
trimMe = [trimMe stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"trime me %@", trimMe);
    orderValueText.text = trimMe;


//}

}
```

but its not giving response as i want.

please guys help me out ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the String Value into the Integer Value. You will the trimmed Zeros. Use this code.

```
    NSString *trimMe = @"000130"; 
    trimMe = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[trimMe intValue]];
    NSLog(@"%@",trimMe);
```